# Create component in Nativescript Angular

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

How to create a component in Nativescript with Angular, using the console to get the files:

- component.component.ts
- component.component.html
  _ component.module.ts
- component-routing.module.ts

[image]

and tried like this:

- ng g component my-name
- ns g component my-name

but I get errors
[image]

How should I do it, is there any way? I'm new to nativescript, please guide me :(